# Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0

Tags: android, google-analytics

Now My company wants add google analytics to our old app.
  I follow the google develper doc ,add libs to android studio,but I get the error when I want to sync gradle :

```css
Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
```

My APP's gradle's version is

```html
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

I find some solutions,like this :

[image: enter link description here]

but it not work.
Anyone have solution thanks

I find ,it will happen when I add the google analytics libs to Project level build.gradle dependencies .the classpath is :classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' ,but ,my app is old and the gradle is :classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3', .when I sync ,it will report the error.when I modify the classpath like this :classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0',it also happend .what can i do ?thank you

[image]

Comment: which version of android studio you using

Comment: you can set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

Comment: `2.1.0` is the latest release.

Comment: My AS version is v1.5

Answer (score 0):

### Whats your Logcat throws

***Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0***

> Classpath is a parameter in the Java Virtual Machine or the Java
>   compiler that specifies the location of user-defined classes and
>   packages.

Open project level **build.gradle** & Call this

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' //or 2.0.0

      }
```

Then `Clean-Rebuild-Sync` Your IDE

Comment: thank you ,but the solution not solve the question,I find ,it will happen when I add the google analytics libs to Project level build.gradle dependencies .the classpath is :classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' ,but ,my app is old and the gradle is :classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3', .when I sync ,it will report the error.when I modify the classpath like this :classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0',it also happend .what can i do ?thank you

Comment: `when I add the google analytics libs`  , you should call `compile 'com.google.android.` package instead jar

Comment: I follow the google analytics document "https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#get-config".I had add "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" and  dependencies {compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'},in the app build.gradle.but it always happend

Comment: you can use `7.3.0/7.8.0`

Comment: thank you ,but some error happened . I use the ''classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1''',and gs '7.3.0 ',it will sync success and build success,but when I run my app it will be crash ,and report ''java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'xxx()' on a null object reference''